# After upgrading to iOS6, all my apps are gone

Tags: ipad, upgrade, ios

I upgraded my iPad to iOS 6.  Now all my apps appear to be gone.  Am I missing something?  Have they moved to a new place?  How do I get them back?

(I don't sync my iPad to a computer, if that is relevant.)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a backup somewhere (on a computer or in iCloud) you must download all apps again from the App Store.

For the next time go to Settings > iCloud > Storage (in the bottom) > Turn on iCloud-backup.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have lost your apps if you upgraded from iOS 5 to iOS 6.  Are you sure they weren't moved to a different page on your home screen?  Did you go from iOS 4 to iOS 6?

If they truly are gone, you can easily get a list of all your previously purchased/downloaded apps by going to the App Store, then the "Updates" tab, then by tapping on "Purchased".

Comment: *"Are you sure they weren't moved to a different page on your home screen?"* - That's entirely possible!  Is there any particular place where I should be looking to find them, now that my iPad is running iOS 6?   (Yes, I'm pretty sure this was an upgrade from iOS 5.)  Anyway, thanks for your answer -- very helpful!

Comment: Just look one screen to the right.  You said that ALL your apps were missing, right?